# Plugin - LLFJ - Lazy Loading for Joomla loads all the images at once

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

I have a problem with LLFJ Plugin,It loads all my images at once,It's not lazy loading them at all.I installed it, I tried with jQuery and mootools but same thing.Also I tried other lazy loading plugins (not for joomla,just plugins for jQuery),I followed the instructions as they was on the documentation but none of them worked, they did the same thing,wich is loading all the images at once. Am I doing something wrong ?

[Link to the website gallery.](http://gruppovatra.com/it/photo-2016)

I'll be very thankful If someone can help me !

Comment: Seems to be working for me in FF49, but it loads images that are just outside the viewport too. I think you should contact the developer though. It's their extension, so their issue.

Comment: I didn't subsicribe to their site to recieve support

Comment: How did you removed it and were wish file please

Answer (score 2):

It's solved, seems like `transition: 800ms` css rule to the `img` tag was the problem. I just removed that and it works fine now.